# Vue.js 3 : a `v-model` looses reactivity when `data()` converted to `setup()`

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Consider this basic example where we have an `input` and a `p` that shows the value of the input:

```js
const App = {
  data() {
    return {
      message: "hello world!"
    };
  }
};


Vue.createApp(App).mount('#root');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="root">
  <input v-model="message"/>
  {{ message }}
</div>
```

When you change the input text it is reflected in the content of the `p`. But if you replace `data()` with `setup()`, the changes to `input` are no longer reflected in `p`:

```js
const App = {
  setup() {
    return {
      message: "hello world!"
    };
  }
};


Vue.createApp(App).mount('#root');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="root">
  <input v-model="message"/>
  {{ message }}
</div>
```

A simple fix is to `ref` the `message`:

```js
const App = {
  setup() {
    const message = Vue.ref("hello world!");
    return {
      message
    };
  }
};


Vue.createApp(App).mount('#root');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="root">
  <input v-model="message"/>
  {{ message }}
</div>
```

But why we have to do it? Why it doesn't work out of the box?

I thought it might be because the object returned from `data()` is made reactive internally but the object returned from `setup()` doesn't because that object might contain not only data but also methods that don't need to be observed but when I check `inputEl.__vueParentComponent.setupState` I see that it's a `Proxy`. So, why it doesn't work?

Comment: Pretty sure it's something to do with patching the DOM

Answer (score 1):

`return {...}` just exposes that values to the outside of setup function, you should always use `ref` or `reactive` to make your data reactive :

```
setup() {
    const message = Vue.ref("hello world!");
    return {
      message
    };
  }
```

You could see the comment [here](https://composition-api.vuejs.org/api.html#setup) that says *`// expose to template`* :

```
<template>
  <div>{{ count }} {{ object.foo }}</div>
</template>

<script>
  import { ref, reactive } from 'vue'

  export default {
    setup() {
      const count = ref(0)
      const object = reactive({ foo: 'bar' })

      // expose to template
      return {
        count,
        object
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

And according to [setup usage with template](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-setup.html#usage-with-templates) :

> If `setup` returns an object, the properties on the object can be accessed in the component's template, as well as the properties of the `props` passed into `setup`

**Conclusion**

the object returned in `setup` function is different than that return from `data` property in option api